# Insert a value in a column seperate by comma

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

Insert a value in a column name e-mail then it display all emails seperated by comma. This email is save at different time but for same id.
Is it possible then how?

Comment: could u explain your question better?

Comment: Please be more clear and show us what have you tried ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to show the comma separated records that belong to same group,be aware of that fact `GROUP_CONCAT` has a default limit of 1024 characters to concat but it can be increased as mentioned in [**docs**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (id INT ,`test` varchar(25))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (id,`test`)
VALUES
    (1,'test@test.com'),
    (1,'test@test.com'),
    (1,'test@test.com'),
    (2,'test2@test.com'),
    (2,'test2@test.com'),
    (2,'test2@test.com')
;

SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(test) emails
FROM
Table1 GROUP BY id
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d9dbc/1)

Comment: could it store emails in same column and same row of a similar id?

Comment: @user3440874 it can store but it highly ***Not Recommended*** please read the concept of [**Database normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) first